# WP Query not limiting amount of posts that's shown

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically i am trying to display the 3 most recent posts from a category on a wordpress site.

The Query gets the posts fine, but does not limit them to 3 posts on the page, it instead shows every posts in that category, Here is the complete code for the page, any ideas?

```
<?php
if (is_front_page( )) {
?>

<style>

.site-inner {
 max-width: 100%;
 }

 </style>

 <div class="sponsor-section">

 <div class="one-third first">


<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query(array( 
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'category_name' => 'general',
)); 

while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>

    <h4><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>                     
    <p><i><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></i></p>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>


    <div class="one-third">
     <!-- MAP start-->
     [4web_scripts id="1"]
     </div>

     <div class="one-third">
     <button>Book Now</button>
     <br />
     <?php putRevSlider("sponsors") ?>
     </div>

     </div>



     <?php }
     ?>
```

Comment: maybe helpful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/181553

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like this it should work just fine:

```
$catquery = new WP_Query(array( 
  'post_type' => 'post'
  'category_name' => 'general',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'nopaging' => true
));
```

If this does not work, do you have sticky posts? They are always shown as far as I know.